# std::function does not match lambda as parameter in fold-expression template function

Tags: c++, sqlite, c++11, clang, arm-linux-gnueabi-g++

In C++ 11 I declared two functions in the same namespace (class `Database`):

```
template <typename... Ts> bool HandleStmt(sqlite3_stmt *pSQL, std::function<void(std::tuple<Ts...>)> f)
```

```
bool Database::WALModeEnabled()
```

I get this error when compiling:

```
source/Database.cpp: In member function 'bool Database::WALModeEnabled()':
source/Database.cpp:180:30: error: no matching function for call to
'Database::HandleStmt(sqlite3_stmt*&, Database::WALModeEnabled()::<lambda(std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)>&)'
  180 |         HandleStmt(pSQL, func);
      |                              ^
In file included from source/Database.cpp:6:
source/include/Database.h:151:36: note: candidate: 'template<class ... Ts> bool Database::HandleStmt(sqlite3_stmt*, std::function<void(std::tuple<_Tps ...>)>)'
  151 |     template <typename... Ts> bool HandleStmt(sqlite3_stmt *pSQL, std::function<void(std::tuple<Ts...>)> f)
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~
source/include/Database.h:151:36: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
source/Database.cpp:180:30: note:   'Database::WALModeEnabled()::<lambda(std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)>' is not derived from 'std::function<void(std::tuple<_Tps ...>)>'
  180 |         HandleStmt(pSQL, func);
      |                              ^
```

`WALModeEnabled` prepares an SQL statement and calls `HandleStmt` with the statement pointer and a lambda containing some code that is executed when the statement is done/found in Database.cpp:

```
bool Database::WALModeEnabled()
{
    sqlite3_stmt *pSQL = nullptr;
    bool WALMode = false;
    if (PrepareStmt(&pSQL, "PRAGMA journal_mode")) {
        auto func = [&WALMode](std::tuple<std::string> wal_from_db) {
            WALMode = (std::get<0>(wal_from_db) == "WAL");
        };
        HandleStmt(pSQL, func);
    }

    CleanStmt(pSQL);
    return WALMode;
}
```

`HandleStmt` wraps SQL statement with `SQLITE_BUSY` handling in a generic function where it is declared in `Database` class Database.h:

```
template <typename... Ts> bool HandleStmt(sqlite3_stmt *pSQL, std::function<void(std::tuple<Ts...>)> f)
{
    bool hasData = true;
    while (hasData) {
        switch (sqlite3_step(pSQL)) {
            case SQLITE_ROW:
                f(selectstmt::make_result<Ts...>(pSQL));
                break;
            case SQLITE_BUSY:
                sqlite3_sleep(SQL_BUSY_TIMEOUT_MS);
                break;
            case SQLITE_DONE:
            case SQLITE_OK:
                hasData = false;
                break;
            default:
                LogError();
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`selectstmt::make_result<Ts...>(pSQL)`  calls the `sqlite3_column_...` functions for any number of types. This works and is used in other parts of the code.

Compiler explorer is able to compile it on MSVC x86 but not on Clang x86-64 (same error). Passing test function `void test(std::tuple<std::string> wal_from_db)` with empty body results in the same error. I expect `HandleStmt` to be called with a lambda with any number and types of parameters.

Comment: lambda is not a `std::function`...

Comment: `template <typename Func>void foo(Func f)` instead?

Comment: While a lambda is convertible to `std::function`, it's in fact convertible to many different specializations of `std::function`, not just one. Besides, user-defined conversions are not considered during template parameter deduction. For these reasons, `Ts` can't be deduced from the lambda argument. You can call `HandleStmt<std::string>(pSQL, func)`, providing the types explicitly. Or, you can explicitly cast the lambda to `std::function`, but that'll be uglier: `HandleStmt(pSQL, std::function<void(std::tuple<std::string>)>{func})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

explicitly casting the lambda in the function call solved the issue.
HandleStmt(pSQL, std::function<void(std::tuplestd::string)>{func})